# In which real life application is BPM actually used?

Tags: business-process-management

What is the role of BPM (BussinessProcessManagement) in a realtime application?
I mean in which cases or where is BPM actually used?
I could get the documentation from the net, but where actually is it used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One definition of BPM is that is combines workflow management (humans interacting) with enterprise application integration (EAI, systems interacting). You can get applications and tools for those applications - sometime embedded - which you can use to define you business process. Then, in a staging process, you can roll out the business process to that system or a set of applications. To execute a business process (BP) you can use a business process engine (e.g. jBPM), and each step of a business process can be represented by a user interaction, a user task, a system task or variations of these. You can have parallel business steps that only once all of these complete can go to the next business process step. And there is much more to that.

Once you have rolled out a business process you can monitor it and collect data for a number of parameters. Often you will be interested how long a business process took and what the limiting factors are, e.g. how many manual steps are required. Then you can go back to the designer tool and modify the process. With data taken from the production system you can then simulate whether your changes are actually an improvement. And if they are you roll it out replacing the previous version.

On a smaller scale you can workflow designer or business process designers to allow user changing a particular part of a process. Often applications have hard-coded business process support with only limited parameterization/configuration. Take an approval process. Which purchases need approval? By whom? Could multiple people approve in parallel thus shortening the purchasing process? You application may offer your users to design the approval process as needed. It would no longer be hard-coded and allow for much better adaptation to the needs of your customer.

These are just a few thought and definitely not a full coverage of this subject. But maybe it already gives some idea.

Answer (score 0):

BPM can be used in Health care application for integrating various systems and in banking field for loans aplication processing where human involvement is involved in different steps for loans approval, and in health care industry it is used mostly used for bundle of claims which we receive every day for cliams processing and for business state in which state to know.
and in The airline Reservation System for ticket booking process how the process moves one one level to another ex: adding passenger to flight.